# Store and retrieve spinner data in Android using SQLite db

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I need to store selected spinner values and retrieve it back from db and display it in another spinner.

So how to store the values i.e using `getselecteditem()`?

And also while retrieving, how to retrieve it back and display in spinner?

```
values.put("year", spinYear.getSelectedItemPosition()); //currently storing position

spinYear.setSelection(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("year")));//retrieving from sqlite .
```

Instead of that, I need to store `selectedItem` and display it in spinner.

Comment: google it there are lot of examples anyways you can refer here  http://coderzpassion.com/android-spinner-get-data-from-sqlite-database/

Comment: That link shows,store data using edit text not from the spinner. I need to store the spinner selected data and store it in db.

Comment: u got hint get value from spinner and fire query according to that value to get the desired output